# fullpage.js snap top of viewport to top of section

Tags: jquery, html, css, fullpage.js

I added the "fp-auto-height" class to the top section in my fullpage.js page to make it smaller than fullscreen. Now, after scrolling down, I cannot scroll back up.

I looked into it and realized this happens because the scrolling mechanism snaps bottom of the section to the bottom of the viewport. Since there isn't anything above the first section, it cannot snap the bottom of it to the bottom of the viewport.

How can I make it snap the top of the section to the top of the viewport (and not bottom-to-bottom)

Thanks!

Comment: Just to let you know, this will be possible in fullpage.js 2.7.7, which is not under development.

Comment: @Alvaro Thanks for the reply :) What do you mean by *not* under development?

Comment: Sorry a mistake :D I wanted to say it is under development. In fact, you can get [the development version](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/blob/dev/jquery.fullPage.js) and test it yourself.

Comment: @Alvaro Awesome, thanks!

Comment: @Alvaro, are there classes in the development version that are not documented in the main documentation?

Comment: This is not the place to ask. Contact me by mail or twitter if you have any question regarding that topic.

Answer (score 0):

> I added the "fp-auto-height" class to the top section in my fullpage.js page

It has no sense to have an auto-height first section.

[The documentation](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#creating-smaller-sections) says:

> It is important to realise that it doesn't make sense to have all of your sections using this feature. If there is more than one section in the initial load of the site, the plugin won't scroll at all to see the next one as it will be already in the viewport.

Basically the plugin is not supposed to be used the way you are using it. 
The auto-height option was introduced as a way to deal with footers and other sections of the site. Not with your first section.

Comment: Thank you for your reply :) 
I do not use it on every section, I only use it for the top section, to be used as a "header". Similar to what they meant, only on top.

Comment: The problem is, fullpage.js created it to deal with footers, not headers. So it won't work for your case I'm afraid.